# installing tomcat7 using puppet on CentOs

Tags: solr, tomcat7, puppet

so my idea was to install tomcat7 using puppet, and then deploy the war file of Solr as a web app. Here is what i found.

There are many tomcat7 modules on [puppet forge](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/)  but none of them work out of box, and i am not sure if any of them actually work and a lot of them pertains to have code as documentation.

Take **puppet module install fhuertas-tomcat7** as first example:

installs fhuertas-tomcat7 (v0.0.1)

i get an error, when i run:

```
sudo puppet apply --modulepath=/home/qa/puppet_qa/modules/ -e "include tomcat7" --debug
```

Error: Could not find data item service_path in any Hiera data file and no default supplied

and similar scenario follows for :

```
puppet module install llehmijo-tomcat7_rhel ( no longer maintained )
```

https://github.com/Spredzy/puppet-tomcat7 ( claims to be for CentOs ) but has an Apt (apt for centos ??) pre-requisite, plus it did not install either.

All i want to do is to install tomcat7 via puppet, and then install Solr. seems to be a simple request. Meanwhile i am working on my own to resolve the exact issue, and was able to install and run tomcat7, but not sure how i can install tomcat-users.xml

here is a portion of my init.pp

```
exec {'start service':
command => 'sh "startup.sh"',
cwd => "/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin",
path => '/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/bin/:/usr/bin:/bin',
#require => File['/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/conf/tomcat-users.xml']
}
```

so if i un-comment the require =>  File[]

```
Error: Could not find dependency File[/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/conf/tomcat-users.xml] for Exec[start service]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
file { "/etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml":
    owner => 'root',
    require => Package['tomcat'],
    notify => Service['tomcat'],
    content => template('tomcat/tomcat-users.xml.erb')
  }
```

This works, as for the modules not working on puppet forge , and github, i think there is no resolution as if not working then these modules can be taken as guidelines, or hints.

Answer (score 1):

I used the supported one https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/tomcat and following the examples everything was properly installed using packages (at least on Ubuntu). It is also possible to install it from source.
https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-tomcat/tree/master/examples. See the example below:

```
class { 'java': }
class { 'tomcat':
  install_from_source => false,
  user => 'tomcat7',
  require => Class['java']
}

tomcat::instance { 'tomcat7':
  package_name => 'tomcat7',
  require => Class['tomcat']
}->
tomcat::instance { 'tomcat7-admin':
  package_name => 'tomcat7-admin',
}->
tomcat::config::server::tomcat_users {
 'tomcat-admin':
    catalina_base => '/var/lib/tomcat7',
    element  => 'user',
    password => 'test',
    roles => ['manager-gui','admin'];
 'deployer':
    catalina_base => '/var/lib/tomcat7',
    element => 'user',
    password => 'deployer',
    roles => ['manager-script'];
}->
tomcat::service { 'tomcat7':
  service_ensure => running,
  catalina_base => '/var/lib/tomcat7',
  require => Tomcat::Instance['tomcat7']
}
```